# Update a JAR file on UNIX system

Tags: unix

I have a JAR file on a UNIX system for which owner is a different user.

Is there a way in which I can add or update a .class file present in the JAR archive?

Comment: If you lack the permission to the edit the file, then letting you add to or update its contents would indicate a rather broken security model, don't you think?

Comment: That depends on what permissions are applied to the file, and if you have write access to it. If you do not have to write access, then your options would be to copy it (assuming you have read access), modify it, then use that copy instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you have permission to write to the file then yes, like this:

```
jar uf foo.jar foo.class
```